# Finding the Average of a Column With Multiple Group Bys PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to Postgres and would like to query the following table to get the average % of the total allocation at a user level from the following table:

[image: Layout of the current table]

e.g. I would like to get

```
Column 1       Columns 2
Label         Avg Percent of the total from each user for a given label
Chickens        0.347
Goats           0.335
```

Does anybody understand what I am asking and would be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to add more details. How do you calculate *Chickens        0.347*?

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for `group by`?

```
select label, avg(percent_of_total)
from t
group by label;
```